# A "Git" like workflow using Subversion?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, commit, configuration-management

In my previous team we used Git. I am used to performing small and many commits, that represent the ongoing progress of my development work.

When ready, i usually push changes to the central git repository to share changes with other team members.

In the current organization i work in, SVN is used, and this whole workflow is not available.

What happens is, that i am working on feature X for a very long period of time, and commit my entire feature as a single commit, containing many files.

This is cumbersome and error prone.

I wonder what would be the ideal dev workflow using Subversion? is there anything that might resemble the Git workflow i was used to ?

Answer (score 3):

You should convince new team to switch to git. If you can't do that for whatever reason, you could still use git for yourself via `git svn` - it will let you work using git primitives and automatically save it back into svn as necessary. Progit (official Git book) has [whole chapter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion) devoted to this very topic.

Comment: +1 for the "git svn" tip. (Although I personally agree that a switch to git might be an improvement, that is not really the question. :) )

Answer (score 3):

> i am working on feature X for a very long period of time, and commit my entire feature as a single commit, containing many files.

It's your fault. Subversion has **real** branches (contrary to Git's "branches"), long work can (and must, really) be separated into branch, in which you can have any amount of (small|big) commits, and final result have to be merged to mainline (/trunk most times) as single commit in trunk, but you still have detailed history in your branch.

With git-svn you can continue to use your preferred git-client for most of tasks (but not for all, sometimes native svn-client will be a must)

Comment: If you get used to git model, it is very difficult (almost impossible) to adjust to svn. And svn "real" branches simply suck. I won't go into details - no point in starting flame war.

Comment: @mvp - "If you get used to git model, it is very difficult (almost impossible) to adjust to svn" - thus: Git suxxx, because it suxxx and  
poison git-users, turning human with brain into brainless Git-fanatics